# can't choose type enumeration while creating new entity on jhipster

Tags: jhipster

when I try to create a new entity on jhipster ,if I choose to add a field with type enumeration I get this problem:

```
The entity Produit is being created.
The entity Produit is being created.

Generating field #1

? Do you want to add a field to your entity? Yes
? What is the name of your field? categorie
? What is the type of your field? Enumeration (Java enum type)
? Do you want to add validation rules to your field? (y/N) "
```

I can't find the question which says "what is the class name of your enumeration?"

I'm using openjdk 11.0.7 , node v12.16.3 on windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very likely a regression of JHipster 6.9.0, I have been able to reproduce it in 6.9.0 while it works fine in 6.8.0.

You should report this issue on github; https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues

As a workaround, you can install 6.8.0 with `npm install -g generator-jhipster@6.8.0` and start a new project from an empty directory because jhipster 6.9.0 is already installed locally in your current project dir.

Alternatively you could use JDL, I tested it in 6.9.0, it works fine, create an `entities.jdl` file like below (see https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/) and then import it with `jhipster import-jdl entities.jdl`

```
enum Categorie {
  ONE, TWO
}


entity Produit {
  categorie Categorie
}
```

Comment: I am also currently facing the issue .

Comment: thanks , it's work fine with 6.8.0 version. i've already tryied to use import-jdl commande,but the generator couldn't find file location while using the absolute path

Comment: For the jdl location it depends on which shell you use, if you use powershell :`jhipster import-jdl .\entities.jdl` works fine